# How much CPU memory does langchain program use while running in jupyter notebook?

Tags: memory, cpu, langchain, py-langchain

I want to know how much CPU memory is used when we run a langchain program with a specific LLM model. Also I want to know how much memory does it use based on the size of the data set that we pass in the program.

I use a 64 bit Windows 11 OS. I tried understanding the memory usage from Task Manager, Resource Monitor,HWiNFO64 application but did not quite get how much memory the program consumes.

I used the following resources:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Os5cK0H8EOA
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/resource.html
- https://www.codeproject.com/Forums/1644/System-Admin?df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&select=1058952&tid=1058952.

On the Langchain docs, I did not come across any such page where it is explained.